# Nosetests not recognized on Windows

Tags: python, windows, nose

I have a package that is built with Travis on Linux and on Windows. Tests are executed with nose.

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=terminalplot
```

On Linux all 4 tests are successfully executed.

```
$ nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=terminalplot

....
Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------
terminalplot/__init__.py           1      0   100%
terminalplot/command.py           25     11    56%
terminalplot/terminalplot.py      27      3    89%
terminalplot/version.py            1      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                             54     14    74%
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Ran 4 tests in 0.013s
```

[Linux result](https://travis-ci.org/kressi/terminalplot/jobs/623687156#L214-L225)

On Windows the same code runs without errors as well, however the report says no tests have been executed.

```
$ nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=terminalplot

The command "nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=terminalplot" exited with 0.
```

Coveralls report says some parts have been covered, so I assume something has run.

```
$ coveralls

Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------
terminalplot\__init__.py           1      0   100%
terminalplot\terminalplot.py      27     23    15%
--------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                             28     23    18%
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Ran 0 tests in 0.016s
```

[Windows result](https://travis-ci.org/kressi/terminalplot/jobs/623687161#L94-L103)

Tests are in a test package in unit test classes. Obviously, those tests get found by nose on Linux, I do not know why those tests are not found on Windows.

Project structure

```
.
+- terminalplot
|  +- test
|  |  +- __init__.py
|  |  +- test_terminalplot.py
|  |
|  +- __init__.py
|  +- terminalplot.py
|  +- ...
|
+- ...
```

Tests look like following test

```py
import unittest

class TestCommand(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_list_floats(self):
        self.assertEqual(cli.list_floats("1 0.1 -0.3"), [1, 0.1, -0.3])
```

Complete code is on [Github](https://github.com/kressi/terminalplot/tree/develop)

Since I only have access to Linux, I just try out Windows stuff on Travis. This is rather tedious. So I hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried `--exe` flag?

Comment: @AlanHamlett Unfortunately, this has not changed anything.In the nose docs it also says `--exe` is the default on Windows platform. https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#cmdoption-noexe

Comment: Yes, I figured out the same. To fix it I've switched my project to pytest, which works as expected on Linux, Win, Mac.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Additionally, I use `pytest-cov` for test coverage. Instead of `nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=terminalplot` I run `pytest --cov=terminalplot`.